# Mysql: Create a view showing only a subset of a one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, view, one-to-many

Say I have a one-to-many relationship, such as a table of singers, each of whom has sung number of songs:
    DROP TABLE singers;
    CREATE TABLE singers (
        id bigint not null auto_increment,
        name varchar(255) not null,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

```
INSERT INTO singers (name) VALUES ('Joe'), ('Bob');

DROP TABLE songs;
CREATE TABLE songs (
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    singer_id bigint not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO songs (singer_id, name) VALUES (1, "foo"), (2, "bar"), (1, "baz"), (2, "quux");
```

Assume that the song rows are written out correctly in chronological order, so that for example I could find the most recent song that Joe sang with the query

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE singer_id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Now, suppose I wanted to create a MySQL view that contained a row for each singer and the most recent song sung by that singer.  In other words, a table that looks like this:

```
singer_id   singer_name    song_id   song_name
   1          Joe             3         baz
   2          Bob             4         quux
```

It seems like this would require integrating the ORDER BY / LIMIT clause from above into the view construction/join logic somehow -- but I can't figure out how.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select si.id, si.name, so.name, so.id 
from singers si
inner join songs so on so.singer_id = si.id
where so.id = (select max(songs.id) from songs where songs.singer_id=si.id)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d52c4/21

Comment: Shouldn't `so.song_name` be either a parameter for aggregate or member of GROUP BY clause? Maybe MySQL will be able to handle that, but this seems to be not valid ANSI SQL.

Comment: Nice job, this does at least work with MySQL.  This variant (moving the subquery in the where clause up into the from clause, to avoid the problems mysql seems to have with redundantly executing subqueries) also seems to work:  `select si.id, si.name, so.name, so.id 
from singers si
inner join (select * from (select * from songs order by id desc) as s1 group by singer_id) as so
on so.singer_id = si.id;`

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use GROUP BY for this sort of thing, so here is my solution:

(I made views for convinience, but you don't have to)

```
CREATE VIEW lastsongs AS 
SELECT singers.id, singers.name, MAX(songs.id) AS lastsong
FROM singers
JOIN songs ON songs.singer_id = singers.id
GROUP BY singers.id, singers.name;

CREATE VIEW lastsongnames AS
SELECT lastsongs.name, songs.name AS songname
FROM lastsongs
JOIN songs ON songs.id = lastsongs.lastsong;

SELECT name, songname FROM lastsongnames;
```